# How to create zip:// protocol in GeckoFx to read password protected zip files?

Tags: vb.net

I'm create a program in VB.NET with embedded GeckoFx browser. How to creating zip:// protocol to read from password protected zip file?

Example: zip:///d:/dir/file.zip!/idnex.html

Note: jar:file:///d:/dir/file.zip!/idnex.html is not read the index.html from password protected ZIP file.

Initialize Gecko in MainWindow class:

```
Sub New()
  InitializeComponent()
  Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox64")
  Xpcom.RegisterFactory(
    New Guid("66170430-e4ec-11e9-aaef-0800200c9a66"),
    "Zip protocol handler",
    "@mozilla.org/network/protocol;1?name=zip",
     New ZipFacrory)
End Sub
```

The ZipFactory class:

```
Class ZipFacrory
  Implements nsIFactory

  Public Function CreateInstance(aOuter As nsISupports, ByRef iid As Guid) As IntPtr Implements nsIFactory.CreateInstance
    Return Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(New ZipProtocolHandler(), GetType(nsIProtocolHandler))
  End Function

  Public Sub LockFactory(lock As Boolean) Implements nsIFactory.LockFactory
  End Sub

End Class
```

The ZipProtocolHandler class:

```
Class ZipProtocolHandler
  Implements nsIProtocolHandler

  Public Sub GetSchemeAttribute(aScheme As nsACStringBase) Implements nsIProtocolHandler.GetSchemeAttribute
    aScheme.SetData("zip")
  End Sub

  Public Function GetDefaultPortAttribute() As Integer Implements nsIProtocolHandler.GetDefaultPortAttribute
    Return -1
  End Function

  Public Function GetProtocolFlagsAttribute() As UInteger Implements nsIProtocolHandler.GetProtocolFlagsAttribute
    Return nsIProtocolHandlerConsts.URI_NOAUTH Or nsIProtocolHandlerConsts.URI_IS_LOCAL_FILE Or
      nsIProtocolHandlerConsts.URI_IS_LOCAL_RESOURCE
  End Function

  Public Function NewURI(aSpec As nsAUTF8StringBase, aOriginCharset As String, aBaseURI As nsIURI) As nsIURI Implements nsIProtocolHandler.NewURI
    Dim mutator As nsIStandardURLMutator = Xpcom.CreateInstance(Of nsIStandardURLMutator)("@mozilla.org/network/standard-url-mutator;1")
    Return mutator.Init(nsIStandardURLConsts.URLTYPE_STANDARD, -1, aSpec, aOriginCharset, aBaseURI).Finalize()
  End Function

  Public Function NewChannel2(aURI As nsIURI, aLoadinfo As nsILoadInfo) As nsIChannel Implements nsIProtocolHandler.NewChannel2
    Return New ZipChannel(aURI, aLoadinfo)
  End Function

  Public Function NewChannel(aURI As nsIURI) As nsIChannel Implements nsIProtocolHandler.NewChannel
    Return NewChannel2(aURI, Nothing)
  End Function

  Public Function AllowPort(port As Integer, scheme As String) As Boolean Implements nsIProtocolHandler.AllowPort
    Return False
  End Function

End Class
```

The ZipChannel class:

```
Class ZipChannel
  Implements nsIChannel

  Private status As Integer
  Private loadGroup As nsILoadGroup
  Private loadFlags As UInteger
  Private originalURI As nsIURI
  Private owner As nsISupports
  Private notificationCallbacks As nsIInterfaceRequestor
  Private contentType As String
  Private contentCharset As String
  Private loadInfo As nsILoadInfo
  Private contentLengt As Long
  Private contentDisposition As UInteger
  Private contentDispositionFilename As Integer

  Sub New(aURI As nsIURI, aloadInfo As nsILoadInfo)
    originalURI = aURI
    loadInfo = aloadInfo
  End Sub

  Public Sub GetNameAttribute(aName As nsAUTF8StringBase) Implements nsIChannel.GetNameAttribute, nsIRequest.GetNameAttribute
    aName.SetData("Zip channel")
  End Sub

  Public Function IsPending() As Boolean Implements nsIChannel.IsPending, nsIRequest.IsPending
    Return False
  End Function

  Public Function GetStatusAttribute() As Integer Implements nsIChannel.GetStatusAttribute, nsIRequest.GetStatusAttribute
    Return status
  End Function

  Public Sub Cancel(aStatus As Integer) Implements nsIChannel.Cancel, nsIRequest.Cancel
    status = aStatus
  End Sub

  Public Sub Suspend() Implements nsIChannel.Suspend, nsIRequest.Suspend
    status = GeckoError.NS_OK
  End Sub

  Public Sub [Resume]() Implements nsIChannel.Resume, nsIRequest.Resume
    status = GeckoError.NS_OK
  End Sub

  Public Function GetLoadGroupAttribute() As nsILoadGroup Implements nsIChannel.GetLoadGroupAttribute, nsIRequest.GetLoadGroupAttribute
    Return loadGroup
  End Function

  Public Sub SetLoadGroupAttribute(aLoadGroup As nsILoadGroup) Implements nsIChannel.SetLoadGroupAttribute, nsIRequest.SetLoadGroupAttribute
    loadGroup = aLoadGroup
  End Sub

  Public Function GetLoadFlagsAttribute() As UInteger Implements nsIChannel.GetLoadFlagsAttribute, nsIRequest.GetLoadFlagsAttribute
    Return loadFlags
  End Function

  Public Sub SetLoadFlagsAttribute(aLoadFlags As UInteger) Implements nsIChannel.SetLoadFlagsAttribute, nsIRequest.SetLoadFlagsAttribute
    loadFlags = aLoadFlags
  End Sub

  Public Function GetOriginalURIAttribute() As nsIURI Implements nsIChannel.GetOriginalURIAttribute
    Return originalURI
  End Function

  Public Sub SetOriginalURIAttribute(aOriginalURI As nsIURI) Implements nsIChannel.SetOriginalURIAttribute
    originalURI = aOriginalURI
  End Sub

  Public Function GetURIAttribute() As nsIURI Implements nsIChannel.GetURIAttribute
    Return originalURI
  End Function

  Public Function GetOwnerAttribute() As nsISupports Implements nsIChannel.GetOwnerAttribute
    Return owner
  End Function

  Public Sub SetOwnerAttribute(aOwner As nsISupports) Implements nsIChannel.SetOwnerAttribute
    owner = aOwner
  End Sub

  Public Function GetNotificationCallbacksAttribute() As nsIInterfaceRequestor Implements nsIChannel.GetNotificationCallbacksAttribute
    Return notificationCallbacks
  End Function

  Public Sub SetNotificationCallbacksAttribute(aNotificationCallbacks As nsIInterfaceRequestor) Implements nsIChannel.SetNotificationCallbacksAttribute
    notificationCallbacks = aNotificationCallbacks
  End Sub

  Public Function GetSecurityInfoAttribute() As nsISupports Implements nsIChannel.GetSecurityInfoAttribute
    '???
    Return Nothing
  End Function

  Public Sub GetContentTypeAttribute(aContentType As nsACStringBase) Implements nsIChannel.GetContentTypeAttribute
    aContentType.SetData(contentType)
  End Sub

  Public Sub SetContentTypeAttribute(aContentType As nsACStringBase) Implements nsIChannel.SetContentTypeAttribute
    contentType = aContentType.ToString
  End Sub

  Public Sub GetContentCharsetAttribute(aContentCharset As nsACStringBase) Implements nsIChannel.GetContentCharsetAttribute
    aContentCharset.SetData(contentCharset)
  End Sub

  Public Sub SetContentCharsetAttribute(aContentCharset As nsACStringBase) Implements nsIChannel.SetContentCharsetAttribute
    contentCharset = aContentCharset.ToString
  End Sub

  Public Function GetContentLengthAttribute() As Long Implements nsIChannel.GetContentLengthAttribute
    Return contentLengt
  End Function

  Public Sub SetContentLengthAttribute(aContentLength As Long) Implements nsIChannel.SetContentLengthAttribute
    contentLengt = aContentLength
  End Sub

  Public Function Open() As nsIInputStream Implements nsIChannel.Open
    'NS_ERROR_IN_PROGRESS (if the channel is reopened)
    Throw New NotImplementedException()
  End Function

  Public Function Open2() As nsIInputStream Implements nsIChannel.Open2
    Throw New NotImplementedException()
  End Function

  Public Sub AsyncOpen(aListener As nsIStreamListener, aContext As nsISupports) Implements nsIChannel.AsyncOpen
    'example zip://impera.zip!/folder/file.png
    Dim uri As Uri = originalURI.ToUri
    Dim filespec As String = uri.Authority & uri.AbsolutePath
    Dim t As String() = filespec.Split({"!/", "!\", "!"}, StringSplitOptions.None)

    ' MIME type
    Dim ms = Xpcom.CreateInstance(Of nsIMIMEService)("@mozilla.org/mime;1")
    Dim mime As nsACString = New nsACString
    ms.GetTypeFromURI(originalURI, mime)
    SetContentTypeAttribute(mime)

    contentCharset = Text.Encoding.Default.WebName
    aListener.OnStartRequest(Me, aContext)
    Try
      Using zip As ZipFile = New ZipFile(t(0))
        Using zipstream As System.IO.Stream = zip(t(1)).OpenReader(kulcs), sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(zipstream, Text.Encoding.Default)
          Dim data As String = sr.ReadToEnd
          Dim s = New nsAString
          s.SetData(data)
          Dim converter = Xpcom.CreateInstance(Of nsIConverterOutputStream)("@mozilla.org/intl/converter-output-stream;1")
          Dim size As UInteger = zipstream.Length
          Dim storagestream = Xpcom.CreateInstance(Of nsIStorageStream)("@mozilla.org/storagestream;1")
          storagestream.Init(8192, size)
          converter.Init(storagestream.GetOutputStream(0), Text.Encoding.Default.WebName) 'UTF-8   Text.Encoding.Default.BodyName
          converter.WriteString(s)
          converter.Close()
          Dim stream = storagestream.NewInputStream(0)
          aListener.OnDataAvailable(Me, aContext, stream, 0, stream.Available)
        End Using
      End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    aListener.OnStopRequest(Me, aContext, GeckoError.NS_OK)
  End Sub

  Public Sub AsyncOpen2(aListener As nsIStreamListener) Implements nsIChannel.AsyncOpen2
    AsyncOpen(aListener, Nothing)
  End Sub

  Public Function GetContentDispositionAttribute() As UInteger Implements nsIChannel.GetContentDispositionAttribute
    Return contentDisposition
  End Function

  Public Sub SetContentDispositionAttribute(aContentDisposition As UInteger) Implements nsIChannel.SetContentDispositionAttribute
    contentDisposition = aContentDisposition
  End Sub

  Public Sub GetContentDispositionFilenameAttribute(aContentDispositionFilename As nsAStringBase) Implements nsIChannel.GetContentDispositionFilenameAttribute
    aContentDispositionFilename.SetData(contentDispositionFilename)
  End Sub

  Public Sub SetContentDispositionFilenameAttribute(aContentDispositionFilename As nsAStringBase) Implements nsIChannel.SetContentDispositionFilenameAttribute
    contentDispositionFilename = aContentDispositionFilename.ToString
  End Sub

  Public Sub GetContentDispositionHeaderAttribute(aContentDispositionHeader As nsACStringBase) Implements nsIChannel.GetContentDispositionHeaderAttribute
    '???
    'aContentDispositionHeader.SetData("inline")
    'aContentDispositionHeader.SetData("Content-Disposition: inline")
  End Sub

  Public Function GetLoadInfoAttribute() As nsILoadInfo Implements nsIChannel.GetLoadInfoAttribute
    Return loadInfo
  End Function

  Public Sub SetLoadInfoAttribute(aLoadInfo As nsILoadInfo) Implements nsIChannel.SetLoadInfoAttribute
    loadInfo = aLoadInfo
  End Sub

  Public Function GetIsDocumentAttribute() As Boolean Implements nsIChannel.GetIsDocumentAttribute
    Return False
  End Function

End Class
```

Test HTML page (D:/index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>My First Heading</h1>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p><img src="zip:///d:/web.zip!/truck.png"/><img src="truck.png"/></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The image does not load from the web.zip file.

[image]

But the channel works:

```
Dim uri = IOService.CreateNsIUri("zip:///d:/web.zip!/truck.png")
Dim ch As nsIChannel = IOService.NewChannelFromUri(uri)
Dim list = New Listener
ch.AsyncOpen(list, Nothing)
```

The Listener class:

```
Class Listener
  Implements nsIStreamListener

  Public Sub OnStartRequest(aRequest As nsIRequest, aContext As nsISupports) Implements nsIStreamListener.OnStartRequest
  End Sub

  Public Sub OnStopRequest(aRequest As nsIRequest, aContext As nsISupports, aStatusCode As Integer) Implements nsIStreamListener.OnStopRequest
  End Sub

  Public Sub OnDataAvailable(aRequest As nsIRequest, aContext As nsISupports, aInputStream As nsIInputStream, aOffset As ULong, aCount As UInteger) Implements nsIStreamListener.OnDataAvailable
    Try
      Dim ss = Gecko.IO.InputStream.Create(aInputStream)
      Dim fs = System.IO.File.Create("d:\truck2.png")
      ss.CopyTo(fs)
      fs.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
  End Sub

  Private Sub nsIRequestObserver_OnStartRequest(aRequest As nsIRequest, aContext As nsISupports) Implements nsIRequestObserver.OnStartRequest
  End Sub

  Private Sub nsIRequestObserver_OnStopRequest(aRequest As nsIRequest, aContext As nsISupports, aStatusCode As Integer) Implements nsIRequestObserver.OnStopRequest
  End Sub
End Class
```

The D:/truck.png and D:/truck2.png are same.

Why doesn't the picture appear in browser?

Comment: have you  looked at nsIIOService? (I haven't tired it but it looks like it has some API's that might help)